# How can I replace a single App Icon

Tags: icons, themes

How can I replace a single Icon (In my case Inkscape and terminator) without interfering with my current Icon theme.

Since I use the elementary+ Icon theme it has an orange Inkscape Icon and I don't find anything Orange in it therefore I made a couple of different Icons for it following the HIG. How do I place these Icons so that it Do Not Replace the Old Theme Icons (i.e. there files) but my icons are used in the system.

Comment: Why aren't you contributing them to elementary+? To be honest, I don't like the elementary+ Inkscape icon, either...

Comment: becuse I do know that a lot of people are doing fine with the default Orange Icon

Comment: @Adityaultra You could propose your new icon to the elementary+ maintainers nontheless; I'm under the impression they're very grateful for every contributors and if they like your icon, I'm sure they'd accept it.

Comment: Here's My icon http://imgur.com/MHimp43

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I also wanted to customize some icons from elementaryPlus theme. Here is a solution which however requires a little bit of command line juggling. Basically I created a custom icon theme which inherits from the original elementaryPlus theme:

```
# Make sure the target directory exists
mkdir ~/.icons

# Copy original elementaryPlus icon theme
cp -r /usr/share/icons/elementaryPlus ~/.icons

# Rename new icon theme
cd ~/.icons && mv elementaryPlus elementaryPlusCustomized

# Remove existing icons from new icon theme
cd ~/.icons/elementaryPlusCustomized && find . -type f -not -name index.theme -delete

# Edit index.theme file from new icon theme and change Name and Inherits values:
# Name=elementary+ Customized
# Inherits=elementaryPlus
scratch-text-editor ~/.icons/elementaryPlusCustomized/index.theme

# Use new icon theme
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'elementaryPlusCustomized'
```

Now the icons in the new theme will be preferred over the original ones. It's also safe to update the original elementaryPlus theme.

Comment: You don't even need to copy the whole elementaryPlus theme, all you need is the modified `index.theme`. Put your alternative icons in the corresponding folders, that's all.

Comment: @Rafael Right, you really need just the index.theme file and the directory structure. There are several ways how to achieve it and I didn't want to create the directories manually.