# How can I adjust individual icons in the Moka icon theme?

Tags: release-freya, themes

When adjusting the brightness or volume, the pop up on the top right has a white sun and audio icon, which makes it look invisible, as compared as the default, where the icons are black. Is there was any way to fix it?

In addition, in the wingpanel, the rightmost icon does not exactly fit the theme of all the other icons. Like my previous question, is there anyway I can use the default elementary icons for Wingpanel?

[image]

Comment: You can replace some of the icons by following the answer here http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/521/how-can-i-replace-a-single-app-icon

Answer (score 5):

You can try setting the Moka icon theme to inherit from the elmentary icon theme. Edit the `index.theme` file and add **elementary** to the `Inherits` property:

```
sudo vi /usr/share/icons/Mako/index.theme
```

Edit the `Inherits` property:

```
Inherits=elementary
```

You might have to switch themes, before the changes take affect.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work

Answer (score 0):

This did it for me

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Icons in the 'Use another icon set while keeping the Ubuntu Mono panel icons' section.

Open Terminal and type "sudo pantheon-files /usr/share/icons".

Make a copy of the "elementary" folder.
Rename the folder to a new name.

Open the index.theme file

Change the "Name" field to a new name ("Name=elementary" to "Name=elementary+moka")

Add "Inherits" field to the name of the icon theme you want to use ‘Inherits=Moka’ to the name of the folder of the icons you want to use.(This folder may be in ~/.icons or in /usr/share/icons)

[image]

Save the file and go to appearance preferences to set the new icon theme.

Original Answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/485183/change-the-application-icon-theme-but-not-changing-the-panel-icons

END RESULT(I Did The same Thing)
[image]